# Python 3 loop through subprocess output to search for filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am running a terminal command to list a directory, I would like to loop through each line returned and search for a particular filename, I have this so far...

```
import subprocess

for line in subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l']):
    if "(myfile.txt)" in line: 
        print("File Found")
```

But this is just outputing the list and doesn't seem to be searching for the file, anyone have an example they can point me at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ls` from within `subprocess` would return a `Bytes` Object.
So, first, You might want to convert the returned value to a String.
And then split the `String` with New-Line ("\n") as delimiter.
Afterwards, you can iterate and search for your Needle in the List-Values.

```
import subprocess
# CALLING "subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l']" RETURNS BYTES OBJECT...
# SO WE DECODE THE BYTES INTO STRING, FIRST
# AND THEN SPLIT AT THE NEW-LINE BOUNDARY TO CONVERT IT TO A LIST
for line in bytes.decode(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l'])).split(sep="\n"):
    # NOW WE CAN CHECK IF THE DESIRED FILE IS IN THE LINE
    if "(myfile.txt)" in line:
        print("File Found")
```

Comment: Your explanation is kind of misleading. I think it is not the `ls` function that returns a `Bytes` object but this is what `check_output` returns. Also, the `Bytes` object is iterable. You can try to iterate over it.

Comment: @Tai  Thanks for Pointing that out :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass in the encoding `utf-8` and split it by `\n`.

```
for line in subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l'], encoding="utf-8").split("\n"):
    # print(line)
    if "myfile.txt" in line: 
         print("File Found")
```

As originally, `check_output` was returning bytes, thus we pass in encoding here. Also, since you want to search it line by line, we split it with `\n`. (Tested on Python 3.)

> [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output): ... **By default, this function will return
>   the data as encoded bytes**. The actual encoding of the output data may
>   depend on the command being invoked, so the decoding to text will
>   often need to be handled at the application level.
>
> This behaviour may be overridden by setting universal_newlines to True
>   as described above in Frequently Used Arguments. -- cited from https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something that is more reliable such as `os.listdir` or `glob`:

```
import glob

if glob.glob('myfile.txt'):
    print('File found')
else:
    print('File not found')
```

The `glob.glob` function returns a list of files that match the wildcard. In this case, you will have `['myfile.txt']` if the file exists, or `[]` if not.

Comment: That would be perfectly ideal if he was interested in doing it directly. Perhaps he's just experimenting with the `subprocess` module.... However, if not for any valid reason, your solution would be most appropriate and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
 def find(name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\');
        if name in files:
            print(root,name)
            print("FINISH")
            input()

try:
    s=input("name:  ")
    find(s)
except:
    None
```

Comment: Please also add some info in ordinary text on how this answers OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

to output the contents of a directory, i would recommend the os module.

```
import os

content = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

then you have a searchable list.

But are you sure, your file ist named (myfile.txt) ??